# How to stop the location services after 2 min without any significant move?

Tags: ios, core-location

**My app is in the background**. I would like to **stop** (or pause) **the locationupdate after 2.5 min** detecting that the user didn't move significantly and start to listen instead `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. Their is an option: `PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` but the problem is that this option is a little obscure. We don't really know when the system will pause the GPS (seam only after 20 min) and strangely, at the opposite what the doc say, the system will resume himself the locationUpdate (at least when you will put the app in foreground).

So i have another option: `DistanceFilter`. I can set it to none and the system will wake up my app every 5 seconds with new location (same as before if user didn't move). The problem wake up the app every 5 second seam a little aggressive for the battery (my app will be wake up more than 30 times before i reach the 2.5 min to stop the location services). also it's a disaster when user move not very fast, my app will be constantly wake up every 5 second, and i need only an accuracy of 100 meters :(

So this is my problem, how to stop the locationservices after 2.5 min when their is no significant move ?

Comment: You can check the timestamp of location updates delivered to your location delegate and compare it to a timestamp of when your app moved to the background and then stop location updates. Be aware though, once you stop or pause location updates in the background you cannot turn them back on until your app re-enters the foreground.

Comment: no, because with distancefilter (of 25 meters in my case), i receive only one location updates following by nothing for very long time, still pause will be call automatically (20 min after)

Comment: Exactly; time is a poor criteria to stop location updates.  The biggest energy impact from location services comes from the accuracy you have selected.  10m or less will result in the GPS hardware being powered.  Lower accuracy levels do not result in significant power consumption.

Comment: @Paulw11 how do you compare a value from `didUpdateLocation` with a value from `DidEnterBackground`? Do you mean to observe the `DidEnterBackground` notification?

Comment: @Henry **1.** are you OK with not being able to **re-** `startUpdatingLocation` after it stopped for 2.5 minutes in the background? And have it stopped till it reaches foreground and start again? If you're answer is OK, then what are you going to do if user stopped for 4 minuted and then decided to start moving?! **2.** Do you care or not care?

Comment: @Honey: 1. are you OK with not being able to re- startUpdatingLocation after it stopped for 2.5 minutes in the background => YES because i have also startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges (and regions too) so it's will start  again later when user will move significantly (i need only an accuracy of 100m so it's fine). my only concern is to stop the startUpdatingLocation  when user is not moving (in fact my concern is the battery life, i don't want to drain the battery)

Answer (score 0):

so from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground) you got in AppDelegate this method

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)
```

I will call this `PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` and set a timer after 2min to turn it off.

anyhow also another solution would be to get the current location and set a timer to stop locating after 2min in meantime i will still receive location and check is it more 100m and if it was more i will reset the timer and continue

Comment: PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically is always to true, no matter it's take 20 min for the system to pause the locationUpdates. after how you set a timer in background ??

Comment: You can't use a timer in the background.

Comment: what about background mods?

Comment: what you mean by background mods ?

Comment: sorry, background modes.
here take a look:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html